# How do I print generated values by ascending order?

Tags: c++

Here's my code for my math homework, it's to find x1 and x2.
The formula is : [X1 = a + k * 360] and [X2 = -a + k * 360]
But after some calculation I got ±a + k * 120
Then I want to automatically arranged, but how?

Here's my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int K = -3; K <= 3; K++) {
        double X1 = 30 + K * 120;
        double X2 = -30 + K * 120;
        cout << "\nK = " << K << "\n";
        cout << "|X1 = " << X1 << endl;
        cout << "|X2 = " << X2 << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

So the output are :

```
K = -3
|X1 = -330
|X2 = -390

K = -2
|X1 = -210
|X2 = -270

K = -1
|X1 = -90
|X2 = -150

K = 0
|X1 = 30
|X2 = -30

K = 1
|X1 = 150
|X2 = 90

K = 2
|X1 = 270
|X2 = 210

K = 3
|X1 = 390
|X2 = 330
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The question is : How do I arrange those values automatically?
I expected to print this at he bottom

```
-390, -330, -270, -150, -90, -30, 30, 90, 150, 210, 270, 330, 390
```

There's no other rules, I just want to know how to arrange them by ascending order

Comment: Using a `std::set<double>` would be one simple way.

Comment: Seems like if you print the value of `X2` then `X1` in each iteration they will be in the order you're looking for.

Comment: [How do I arrange datas which i generated with for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337297/how-do-i-arrange-datas-which-i-generated-with-for-loop)
[How do I arrange generated datas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73356657/how-do-i-arrange-generated-datas)

Comment: Currently, you're printing the values in the order they are produced.   If you want them in a different (sorted) order, then you need to store the set of values (e.g. in a container) then sort the values (i.e. sort the container), then print the values after sorting.   This probably means changing your current loop so it stores elements and doesn't print them, then sort after the loop, and another loop to print after sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Since X1<sub>K-1</sub> < X2<sub>K</sub> < X1<sub>K</sub> , you can just print them as you loop, first `X2`, then `X1`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (int K = -3; K <= 3; K++) {
        double X1 = 30 + K * 120;
        double X2 = -30 + K * 120;
        cout << X2 << ", " << X1;
        if (K == 3) {
            cout << endl;
        } else {
            cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E873ovPTe)